# VAR model with pandas + statsmodels in Python

Tags: python, pandas, var, statsmodels

I am an avid user of R, but recently switched to Python for a few different reasons. However, I am struggling a little to run the vector AR model in Python from statsmodels.

Q#1. I get an error when I run this, and I have a suspicion it has something to do with the type of my vector.

```
    import numpy as np
    import statsmodels.tsa.api
    from statsmodels import datasets
    import datetime as dt
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import Series
    from pandas import DataFrame
    import os

    df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
    speedonly = DataFrame(df['speed'])
    results = statsmodels.tsa.api.VAR(speedonly)

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
      results = statsmodels.tsa.api.VAR(speedonly)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\var_model.py", line 336, in __init__
      super(VAR, self).__init__(endog, None, dates, freq)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py", line 40, in __init__
      self._init_dates(dates, freq)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py", line 54, in _init_dates
      raise ValueError("dates must be of type datetime")
    ValueError: dates must be of type datetime
```

Now, interestingly, when I run the VAR example from here https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/docs/source/vector_ar.rst#id5, it works fine.

I try the VAR model with a third, shorter vector, ts, from Wes McKinney's "Python for Data Analysis," page 293 and it doesn't work.

Okay, so now I'm thinking it's because the vectors are different types:

```
    >>> speedonly.head()
         speed
    0  559.984
    1  559.984
    2  559.984
    3  559.984
    4  559.984
    >>> type(speedonly)
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> #DOESN'T WORK

    >>> type(data)
    <type 'numpy.ndarray'> #WORKS

    >>> ts
    2011-01-02   -0.682317
    2011-01-05    1.121983
    2011-01-07    0.507047
    2011-01-08   -0.038240
    2011-01-10   -0.890730
    2011-01-12   -0.388685
    >>> type(ts)
    <class 'pandas.core.series.TimeSeries'> #DOESN'T WORK
```

So I convert speedonly to an ndarray... and it still doesn't work. But this time I get another error:

```
   >>> nda_speedonly = np.array(speedonly)
   >>> results = statsmodels.tsa.api.VAR(nda_speedonly)

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#47>", line 1, in <module>
     results = statsmodels.tsa.api.VAR(nda_speedonly)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\var_model.py", line 345, in __init__
     self.neqs = self.endog.shape[1]
   IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Any suggestions?

Q#2. I have exogenous feature variables in my data set that appear to be useful for predictions. Is the above model from statsmodels even the best one to  use?

Answer (score 4):

When you give a pandas object to a time-series model, it expects that the index is dates. The error message is improved in the current source (to be released soon).

```
ValueError: Given a pandas object and the index does not contain dates
```

In the second case, you're giving a single 1d series to a VAR. VARs are used when you have more than one series. That's why you have the shape error because it expects there to be a second dimension in your array. We could probably improve the error message here. For a single series AR model with exogenous variables, you probably want to use sm.tsa.ARMA. Note that there is a [known bug](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/736) in ARMA.predict for models with exogenous variables to fixed soon. If you could provide a test case for this it would be helpful.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes a lot of sense. In terms of the use case - say you are trying to predict speed, where each speed is associated with a timestamp. Other feature variables that are useful for predictions include location (e.g. state), etc. I'd like to run an AR(p) model with both speed and location. My formula would then look something like: Y_t = a + b_i*Y_t-i +... + c_i*L_t-i + ... + error.

Comment: I get a ValueError ("Currently, you need to give a freq if dates are used."), which according to [http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA.html] should be allowed to be 'None.' I include a frequency ('D'): `model=statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA(c, freq='D')` and it works, but when I try to do `results=model.fit(24)` it throws a TypeError ("'int' object has no attribute 'getitem'). Any thoughts on this?

Comment: The freq issue should be fixed in master, but is not yet released yet. What version of the code are you running?

Comment: For the other issue. See the docstring of fit. It doesn't expect an integer for the first argument.

Comment: Hey @jseabold- I'm using python 2.7.3, statsmodels 0.4, pandas 0.10.1. For frequency 'D', 'M' and 'W' work - but 'H', 'L' and 'S' do not...and it is unclear why.

Comment: You need to upgrade to the current code. This isn't fixed in a release yet. We are going to release 0.5.0 soon, if you can't build the code from source.