# VAR model: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, pandas, var, statsmodels

I am trying to run a VAR algorithm with statsmodels to predict some future values and I got stuck.

I have an array of values like this:

```
php_resp_time = [349.70448833, 304.32462033000002, 228.08079499999999, 245.03481033, 268.90133700000001, 275.58803332999997, ......, etc.]
```

What I did is:

```
>>> mdata = DataFrame(php_resp_time)
>>> output:
                        0
                        0   349.704488
                        1   304.324620
                        2   228.080795
                        3   245.034810
                        4   268.901337
                        5   275.588033
                        etc.


>>> dates = sm.tsa.datetools.dates_from_range('1961', length=len(php_resp_time))  #create a range of random dates
>>> output:                       [datetime.datetime(1961, 12, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1962, 12, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1963, 12, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1964, 12, 31, 0, 0), etc.]


>>> mdata.index = pandas.DatetimeIndex(dates) #assign dates as indexes
>>> data = np.log(mdata).diff().dropna()
>>> output:
                           0
                         1962-12-31 -0.138994
                         1963-12-31 -0.288395
                         1964-12-31  0.071700
                         1965-12-31  0.092944
                         1966-12-31  0.024563                                          
                         1967-12-31  0.047386
                         1968-12-31 -0.048385
                         1969-12-31  0.071730
                         etc.

#now when I am trying to call the VAR model I get this error:
>>>model = sm.tsa.VAR(data)
>>>output:               File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/statsmodels/tsa/vector_ar/var_model.py", line 345, in __init__
                                self.neqs = self.endog.shape[1]
                         IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: what happens if you call print self.endog.shape before the self.neqs = ...?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778753/var-model-with-pandas-statsmodels-in-python). Answered there and answered when you asked on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/pystatsmodels/pwG73C4ErgE).

We don't allow to run a VAR with one variable. Pandas Series are by definition only one variable and VARs are used when you have more than one endogenous variable.

**Edit**: To be more constructive, here's a link to some more documentation. http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/vector_ar.html#var